# Alternative for marquee in CSS3 Opera12 Web Browser

Tags: css, overflow, opera, marquee

I have a requirement in which a lengthy text needs to be aligned within a text area. I tried     "text-overflow: ellipsis;"
But, now I would like to add a marquee effect instead so that text is completely readable as required by the user.

When looked into Opera doc, it seems overflow properties & marquee etc are not yet supported.

So anyone has any alternative solution to my problem?

Comment: You make it sound like `marquee` is something new.

Comment: What Opera doc is that? Official Opera/Presto spec support docs are here: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/.

Comment: Marquee is supported in Opera? can you please give me the exact link? I think I am missing something !